# MeasureOverride and other methods in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having issue with WPF and the way it should be implemented which wondering if experts could advise me. In WPF, in the beginning we keep running into classes which we had never heard of (or let's say it is my case only) and each class has its own new methods.

Today, I'm writing an application using Adorner and now I know I must use MeasureOverride() from FrameworkElement ... yes, I know majority of controls in WPF are from FrameworkElement but how should I know which method should be used?

I see tens of blogs throwing methods and dictating what should be done but what is the best way to know what should be used and how?  I guess all I need to know is that how should I know which method is needed from a particular case. I just don't like to mimic what is done here or there. I hope it is clear what I'm trying to say here.

It worries me that things are getting out of hand and there are too much info to catch up with.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two Pass Layout system in WPF and Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202269/two-pass-layout-system-in-wpf-and-silverlight)

Comment: Are you asking when it is appropriate to implement an Adorner based upon OnRender approaches vs maintaining internal framework element children whose rendering is then controlled via the combination of MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I need to reference my own blog here.

http://csharpramblings.blogspot.ca/2012/05/understanding-wpf-layout-system.html

The article is a short introduction to the WPF layout system, using a custom panel control as an example.